# Create event handler for "x" button on type: 'floating' widget?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo, configurable-map-viewer

How do you create event handler for "x" button on type: 'floating' widget?

"OnClose" fires every time: this.parentWidget.hide(); is called.

I want to intercept the event when the "x" button in the title bar is clicked.

Comment: which dijit is this?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my interpretation of your question, I believe that you'd want an `onClose` method in your widget. This code from the [_FloatingWidgetMixin.js](https://github.com/cmv/cmv-app/blob/master/viewer/js/gis/dijit/_FloatingWidgetMixin.js#L12) file is where that gets handled and directed to your `onClose` method:

```
if (this.parentWidget && this.parentWidget.declaredClass === 'gis.dijit.FloatingWidget' && this.onClose) {
    on(this.parentWidget, 'hide', lang.hitch(this, 'onClose'));
}
```

This would get fired when closing the dialog either by clicking the 'X' OR when the user presses the Escape key.

The [Help Widget](https://github.com/cmv/cmv-app/blob/master/viewer/js/gis/dijit/Help.js#L38) has an example of handling the event when the dialog is opened.